# How do i search in VSCode for the value of a yml key?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml

Our project has a lot of yml files with lots of references to other values in them. For example

```
a:
  b:
    c: ${x.y.z}
```

I want to know of a way, within VSCode or some extension, to easily find the value of ${x.y.z} and the name of the file where it's defined.
Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: why not write that extension yourself if it hasn't been done

Comment: Because I have neither the time nor the inclination to do so. I've got too much else happening in my life. And unless I can write it in Java, I won't be able to write it.

Comment: what is so different about Java and JavaScript? It all depends how desperate **you** need this functionality. I have time but I don't need it.

Comment: 1) I had no idea if the extensions were written in Java, C++, JavaScript or anything else. 2) I know basic JavaScript but that's it 3) I would need to know how to write VSCode extensions, which means learning more than just JavaScript and I don't have the time for that as I said before. 4) I don't need it desperately. That's why I was just looking to see if it already existed. Why is it so hard for you to understand all of this? You do know that people use this site to find things that they want and that already exists, don't you?

Comment: `Why is it so hard for you to understand all of this?` It is not. SO is not a programming service.

Comment: I'm not asking it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=b-shan.jsonyamlkeynavigator&ssr=false#overview

> Deep Key Search: Instantly locate any nested key within your JSON or YAML files. Simply enter a dot-separated key path (e.g., parent.child.key) to jump directly to its location.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).